# Exception evaluating SpringEL with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

i start to use Spring MVC and i have a trouble. I want to get the value of a hashmap with the key. The object ProtoStatus contains a hashmap who i want to get value. I have this error :

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "protoStatus.status.get(30000)"
>   (template: "protoStatusPage" - line 18, col 21)

```
public class ProtoStatus
{
    public HashMap<String, String> status;

    public void computeStatus()
    {
        this.status = new HashMap();

        for (int i=30000; i<30032; i++)
        {
            this.status.put(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(ServerChecker.Check("192.168.0.1", i)));
        }
    }

    public void setStatus(HashMap status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public HashMap getStatus()
    {
        return this.status;
    }

    public String getStatus(int key)
    {
        return (String) this.status.get(key);
    }
}
```

The Spring MVC part :

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute User user, @ModelAttribute ProtoStatus protoStatus)
    {
            protoStatus = new ProtoStatus();
            protoStatus.computeStatus();
            return "protoStatusPage";
    }
```

And Finaly, in the template protoStatusPage.html, i want to get the value for key 30000:

```
<p th:text="${protoStatus.status.get(30000)}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your status attribute is null by default. It only becomes non-null when you call `computeStatus()`. But you're never calling it on the ProtoStatus used by the view:

```
        protoStatus = new ProtoStatus();
        protoStatus.computeStatus();
```

Instead, you create a different one, and call computeStatus() on that one, that is then immediately eligible to garbage collection.

Also, you have a `Map<String, String>`, but your `getStatus()` method, and the expression in your view, tries to get something out of it usig a key of type Integer. That will always return null.

Comment: You're right i do two mistakes, now it works fine, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Your `HashMap<String,String>` contains both the `String` object. So you have to call using

Replace this line

```
<p th:text="${protoStatus.status.get(30000)}" />
```

with

```
<p th:text="${protoStatus.status.get('30000')}" />
```